# Devextreme live update menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

i try work with devextreme + jquery/
and i can understood, how i can do next functionality
i nedd

```
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                selection: {
                    mode: "multiple"
                },
.
.
.
onSelectionChanged: function () {
                        console.log('Hoola!!');
                    var menu = $("#menu").dxMenu('instance');
                    disabledMenu = false;
                    menu.repaint();

                }


 var menuItems = [
    {
     text: "With checked",
     icon: "preferences",
     disabled: disabledMenu,
```

but this not work
how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to disable a dxMenu item is to access the necessary item via the "[items](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxMenu/Configuration/#items)" option. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fktfju1c/

```
$("#button").dxButton({
    text: "Disable the 'DesktopLCD 21' item",
    onClick: function () {
       var menuInstance = $("#menu").dxMenu("instance");
       menuInstance.option("items[2].items[1].disabled", true);
    }
});

$("#menu").dxMenu({
    dataSource: menuItems 
});
```